# Cancelling a service from a notification button

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-service

I'm trying to cancel an upload service from my progress notification using the 'cancel' button.

But I cannot get this working.

**Notification is created**

```
//Intent class changes from first activity then to service when it's uploading.
Intent cancel = new Intent(intentClass, BaseUploadService.class);
PendingIntent cancelUploadIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(intentClass, 0, cancel, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificationicon)
.setContentTitle(title)
.setContentText(filename)
.setAutoCancel(totalAmount > uploadedAmount)
.setProgress((int) totalAmount, (int) uploadedAmount, false)
.addAction(R.string.assignment_icon_group, intentClass.getString(R.string.cancel), cancelUploadIntent)
;
return builder.build();
```

**Listen for intent from notification button.**

```
public class BaseUploadService extends IntentService {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        LogUtils.debug("onStartCommand - BaseUploadService");
        stopSelf();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public BaseUploadService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

Nothing is ever received in the service.
+ there could be multiple services.

Comment: Did you double check your manifest to confirm that `BaseUploadService` is declared correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Change `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` to `PendingIntent.getService()`.

If after that change the service is still not started, try building the notification with `setContentIntent` instead of `addAction`.

Check your manifest to confirm that `BaseUploadService` is declared correctly.